# How to keep dry code with reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently I have to call three different api end points to get the information for some dropdown in a redux form.

The question I have is atm to get the end points into separate sets of state. I currently have three different reduces being imported into the index reducer so I can have them under three state terms. I have nearly the same code in three files:

//reducer/job-board/job_tools

```
        import {FETCH_JOB_TOOLS} from "../../actions/job_list_actions";

    export default function(state = {}, action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case FETCH_JOB_TOOLS:
                return action.payload.data;
            default:
                return state;
        }

    }


////reducer/job-board/job_roles


import {FETCH_JOB_ROLES} from "../../actions/job_list_actions";

export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_JOB_ROLES:
            return action.payload.data;
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Seeing as this code is nearly identical is there a way for me to dry this up and still keep three separate pieces of s

Pleas help.

Thank you.

Comment: These don't need refactoring. These are clear and simple. They are just switch statement syntax.

If you have the same logic in each case then just refactor that into another file and call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `FETCH_JOB` action and pass `job_type` from action parameter. So you'll have one unique `fetch` function in reducer and you'll provide what you're fetching, this should be the key in state for what you're fetching.

`store = { roles: [], tools: [] }`

your reducer will looks like:

```
import {FETCH_JOB} from "../../actions/job_list";

export default function(state = {}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_JOB:
            return {
              ...state,
              [action.job_type]: action.payload.data
            }
        default:
            return {...state};
    }

}
```

note: in this case, it's important to generate a new state with `{ ...state, [...] }` instead of just mutate the previous one.

---

By the way, I am using an array like syntax instead of switch case.

you can use a function to create reducers and provide array containing handlers.

```
import createReducer from './createReducer';

const loginReceived = (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    authData: action.auth
});

// [...]

const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [AUTH_LOGIN_START]: loginStarted,
  [AUTH_LOGIN_COMPLETE]: loginReceived,
  [AUTH_LOGIN_FAIL]: loginFail
};

export default createReducer(initialState, ACTION_HANDLERS);
```

and use this as createReducer function

```
/**
 * Creates a reducer.
 * @param {string} initialState - The initial state for this reducer.
 * @param {object} handlers - Keys are action types (strings), values are reducers (functions).
 * @return {object} A reducer object.
 */
export default (initialState = null, handlers = {}) => (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (!action && !action.type) return state;
  const handler = handlers[action.type];
  return handler && handler(state, action) || state;
};
```

Comment: took me a while to figure it out , but i've got there, thank you very much for your help